# Powershell - concatenate output to csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

First of all this is my first post, so if there is something I should know about the procedure on Stackoverflow please let me know.

Now, let's get to my problem with powershell. I am creating a powershell script that will retrieve SAMaccountname and ipphone attribute, then export them to csv file.

```
Import-Module activedirectory

Get-Aduser -filter {ipphone -like "*"} -properties samaccountname,ipphone | select name,samaccountname,ipphone | export-csv "C:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The result is:

```
namme,samaccount,ipphone
```

Now... I need a column with domain/samaccountname format instead of standalone samaccountname. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [a calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to the property list when using `select`:

```
... | select name,samaccountname,ipphone,@{Label='Username';Expression={"DOMAINNAME\$($_.SamAccountName)"}}
```

Comment: [PowerShell Tip of the Week explaining/demoing calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx)

Comment: @Jona I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Are you trying to merge the properties of two different objects into one object?